# How to prevent my cubits and blocs from getting closed during Flutter widgettests?

Tags: flutter

I am using `Cubits` `Blocs` and `Providers` in my flutter app and also `kiwi DI container`

I have an issue when I have one test file that runs multiple tests `testWidgets`.
The cubit/bloc/provider is either closed/disposed and the next test fails.

If I have those tests in separate files or execute them individually they do pass!

I use `MultiBlocProvider` and do inject the dependencies directly fromt he DI container through a method inject that I have exposed. This works great in real app (not tests)

```
class _AppBlocProviders extends MultiBlocProvider {
  _AppBlocProviders({
    required super.child,
  }) : super(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider(create: (_) => inject<LocaleBloc>()),
          ],
        );
}
```

The test file looks something like this (partial code just to give you the idea)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  setUpAll(() async {
    commonSetUpAll();
  });

  testWidgets(
    'authentication screen',
        (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.runAsync(() async {
        await mockAllNetworkImages(() async {
          final Widget widget =
          await getMainScreenWidget(tester, loggedIn: false);
          await tester.pumpWidget(widget);

          await waitForExistence(tester,
              find.byKey(const Key(AuthenticationScreenKeys.emailField)));

          await _cleanUpTest(tester);
        });
      });
    },
  );

  testWidgets(
    'home screen',
        (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.runAsync(() async {
        await mockAllNetworkImages(
              () async {
            final Widget widget =
            await getMainScreenWidget(tester, loggedIn: true);
            await tester.pumpWidget(widget);

            await waitForExistence(tester, logoutBtnFinder);


            await _cleanUpTest(tester);
          },
        );
      });
    },
  );
}


Future<void> _cleanUpTest(WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 3));
}
```

If I run the tests in isolation they run all fine.

If I run the entire main(file) with both tests, the first test succeeds and the second complains that cubits and blocs are "closed" already.

The same happens for my providers.

```
Once you have called dispose() on a ThemeProvider, it can no longer be used.
```

Bloc error

```
Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close
```

I do inject the test dependencies via `setupCommonAll();` call which in principle just does `unregister` from the Kiwi container and registers other mock singletons.